# Where does a Factory pattern implementation class reside in clean architecture for DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I'm trying to follow clean architecture with DDD using a solution that has the following three project types:

- MyProject.Core (entities, interfaces, and services)
- MyProject.Infrastructure (repositories, eventbus, loggers, factories???)
- MyProject.API (controllers)

I have a factory class `MapperFactory` that implements an interface `IMapperFactory` which returns an `IMapperService` based on a `MapType` passed into the factory. Implementations of `IMapperService` reside in the Core layer.

I'm struggling to understand where the Factory implementation classes should reside.  All my repositories are implemented in the infrastructure project but domain services are implemented in the Core project per clean architecture guidelines (at least how I read them)

I feel like the implementation for the factory should be in the core project because that's where all the implementations that it needs to create reside, but not sure.  If it should be in the core project, what type of object would it be since it's not an entity, service, or interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the purpose of `MapperFactory`?

If your `MapperFactory` maps database object to(and from) domain object then they should go to `Infrastructure` project(as your repository implementations reside there).

If your mapper maps domain object to(and from) view model then they reside in API project.

If your model resides inside `Core` services e.g. you don't want to expose your domains to the outside world and you have some `Contracts` in services to communicate with external world then your `MapperFactory` should reside inside `Core`(assuming `MapperFactory` will map domains to (and from) `Contracts`.